# Sample set 70 and choosing 3 out of 7 columns to be in subset

Tags: r

Hello I have a data set that has several columns, lets say a,b,c,d,e,f,. I have 300,000 rows. I want to a random sample of 70 where columns a=1, b >= 2000, and c="This word" or "That word"

I know how to do create a random sample but I am not sure how to filter the row and only add the columns I need.

```
Sample70set=sample(fulldataframe, 70, replace=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read about logical operators in R [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html). [`sample_n()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/sample.html) is from the `dplyr` package where you can choose the number of samples you want.

```
library(dplyr)

fulldataframe %>%
  filter(a == 1 & b >= 2000 & (c == "This word" | c == "That word")) %>%
  sample_n(size = 70, replace = T)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried this many ways and I still receive an error

Comment: X6304_Assignment_3_Data %>%
  filter(REGION == "vermont" & YEAR >= 2000 & (CONDITION == "good" | c == "excellent")) %>%
  sample_n(size = 70, replace = T)


Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
i Input `..1` is `&...`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: also realize I need to set.seed(80915974) for my random sampling of 70

Comment: I think you forgot to replace the second `c` with `CONDITION`. Try `X6304_Assignment_3_Data %>% filter(REGION == "vermont" & YEAR >= 2000 & (CONDITION == "good" | CONDITION == "excellent")) %>% sample_n(size = 70, replace = T) `

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts—as you're seeing here.